# What other alliterative phrases have become inseparable?

Tags: phrases, adjectives, cliche

Just asking out of idle curiousity. There are some words that just always seem to be found together, such as

> strong, silent type
>
> cool, calm and collected
>
> cheap and cheerful

Can you think of others? Does their alliterativeness doom them to the status of cliché?

*Unrelated: How is it possible that 'cliché' and 'alliteration' do not yet exist as tags on the site? (As a new user I can't create tags.)*

Comment: There, is that better? :-)

Comment: They're not cliché yet! Just little idioms.

Comment: I thought it was "calm, cool and collected"?

Answer (score 9):

- alas and alack
- bear the brunt
- born and bred
- with courage and conviction
- fit as a fiddle
- hearth and home
- kit and kaboodle
- life and limb
- now or never
- spick and span
- vim and vigor
- zig and zag

Comment: I'd say it's "spic and span"... but probably a regional difference.

Comment: @J.M.: to me (from the UK), *spick* is the spelling in this idiom, while *spic* is an ethnic slur (though against which ethnic group, I’m honestly not sure).

Comment: Ah, then it is indeed a regional difference. :) I'm aware of that nasty connotation of "spic", but that came much later than "spic and span" if my memory of the etymology is correct.

Comment: @DLL: *Spic* is an ethnic slur for Hispanics.

Comment: Now *spick* really does not get used other than in that idiom. I can't think *alack* is used independently much either.

Answer (score 4):

Filling in some letters joshdick missed:

- Dearly departed
- Goodness gracious (thanks for the tip)
- jump for joy
- mop and maw (a child making a face)
- pride and prejudice
- road rage

And some duplicates:

- Always avoid alliteration
- hems and haws

Comment: Suggestion: "Goodness gracious" is probably more common than "God is gracious".

Comment: @gk: you forgot "great balls of fire". :D

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of filling out the alphabet (this answer is community wiki, so please help where I’m still coming up blank):

- each and every;
- I?
- over and out
- Q?
- time and tide, top and tail
- up and under(?)
- warp and weft (or woof); wax and wane; world wide web…
- X?
- Yin and Yang; you and yours.

Of course, alliteration is really about phonemes not letters (as the OP exemplifies with *cheap and cheerful*), so we should really try to collect more than just the alphabet:

- short, sharp shock
- through thick and thin
- then and there
- whys and wherefores (depending on dialect, this [may or may not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_wh#Wine-whine_merger) deserve separation from the other w’s above)
- trick or treat

Comment: I'd give almost anything to see some alliteration under "X"... :D

Comment: How about some "zh"?

Comment: @SamB: sadly, *zh* doesn’t occur word-initially in English — along with *ng* and a few of our other more temperamental consonants…

Answer (score 1):

A few others come to mind:

- Kith and kin
- Head over heels

The latter should evoke someone tumbling, usually in love, but most of our heads are normally above our heels. Perhaps the phrase should be "heels over head in love."

Answer (score 0):

- Black is Beautiful
- Terrible twos

Comment: @Scott Mitchell: I missed the request for alliterations in the title.  This answer has been updated.